# How to protect a website with HTTPS using a digitalocean certificate?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, https, lets-encrypt, digital-ocean

I have deployed a website on a Digital Ocean droplet that listens on port 80, i.e. vanilla HTTP. I would like to protect the website using HTTPS, and it seemed like this would be a simple process using DO's Let's Encrypt integration under the Security -> Certificates section. It was as simple as...

1. Click on "Add Certificate"
2. Select the domain name of my website... [testingtestingmiccheck123.com](https://testingtestingmiccheck123.com)
3. Click on "Generate Certificate"

However, after doing this simple process, my website is still being served over simple HTTP. Am I doing something wrong here? Is this not actually what this feature of DO was intended to be used for?

Comment: I believe just adding new certificate in general won't make your web app/site listen and respond over HTTPS - additional DNS configuration may be required (to make HTTPS default) as well as configuration of your web server to respond over HTTPS - I think you need more details on whether you did anything on this side. Also I assume you aware that feature you described works only when your DNS name managed by DO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are functions for higher level DO services (e.g. load balancers), not meant to add a cert to a single droplet.

Since a droplet is just a Linux VM (or whatever OS you chose), you add a cert in the usual way, e.g. by installing certbot in the VM and running it.